# C# How to draw values onto a 2D array with a user input

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console-application

Alright I have a

```
        string[,] grid = new string[3, 3] {{" "," "," "},
                                           {" "," "," "},
                                           {" "," "," "}};
```

and I have a code in which I get the user to input the coordinates for x and y in this kind of form (x,y(eg 2,2)), The problem I seem to have is how to actually draw a symbol/char in the actual array, how would I go about it, in the Main?

Comment: `how to actually draw a symbol/char in the actual array` ???

Comment: Like I want the compiler to draw an X into one of the spaces by providing the coordinates 2,2 and the compiler replacing that box with an X instead of a blank space

Comment: @Chaus do you need help with understanding how to write the symbol to the that coordinate or rather help with understanding how to display your grid?

Comment: @Chaus do you still need help or did you solve it?

Comment: `compiler replacing that box with an X instead of a blank space` Seems  like you need to read some docs about c#, compilers etc.....

Answer (score 3):

For the example's sake let's say you want to input the symbol $ in the bottom right hand corner of your grid. You do so like this:

```
grid[2,2] = "$";
```

So now your array will look like this if you print it:

```
{{" "," "," "},
 {" "," "," "},
 {" "," ","$"}};
```

Don't forget arrays are 0 based so in your case there is no 3 slot, just 0,1, and 2.

If you'd like to know how to output that grid to the console try:

```
    int rowLength = grid.GetLength(0);
    int colLength = grid.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", grid[i, j]));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

EDIT: You asked how to take the user's input and then place the symbol where they specified:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the x-Coordinate");
int x = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the y-Coordinate");
int y = Console.ReadLine();

grid[x,y] = "$";

//then redraw the grid if you desire using the code above
```

Comment: So how would I tailor this code to work with a Subroutine that outputs the value of XCoordinate and YCoordinate and then uses those two to actually output that symbol into that specified location?
SO I have a subroutine that prompts the user to input the values eg 2,2, how would I get to have those values be used in that code?

Comment: Okay then you want to store the user's input into a variable, I'll show you in my answer, I'll add an edit

Comment: Grand Thank you :)

Comment: Is that what you were looking for? @Chaus

Comment: Yes it is, the code I have doesn't come out with any kind of syntax, but it seems to not have the desired effect on the code maybe you'll know whats wrong http://imgur.com/a/pEzZ6

Comment: what do you mean by "Doesn't come out with any syntax"? Do you mean to say the block of code that should display the grid doesn't display the grid you expect? Can you run the code and show me the output? Not sure what you mean by "not have the desired effect on the code"?

Comment: So this is after the input 1,1 it doesn't seem to put it onto the board, but just leaves it blank and moves onto the next coord http://imgur.com/a/0wJKF

Comment: seems like perhaps the for loops arent going through. Can you put a break point at line 30 and then mouse over the Xlength and Ylength values on lines 22 and 23 and tell me their values?

Comment: Or even easier throw your code into a pastebin and I can debug it myself to see what's wrong

Comment: The grid is in this kind of arrangement as a .txt          +---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+

Comment: So you're never actually writing the coordinates because you get stuck in a while loop. See how you've written: `while (!GameHasBeenWon)` on line 58? You never set that to true in your loop so you keep on looping

Comment: Would changing it to GameHasBeenWon == true fix the problem then?

Comment: Yes but then you would only have 1 guess. I don't think you placed that while loop where you meant to. Ideally you should have your user entry function, then a board displayer function inside the loop. You also haven't written a condition that makes GameHasBeenWon turn to true. How is the program supposed to know when someone's won?

Comment: I see, would changing it to false make it so that It will loop and then create a when GameHasBeenWon statement = true in main and from that make it to loop until a game has been won or drawn?

Comment: Your code is only doing one thing at a time. So if you're stuck in the while loop, changing `GameHasBeenWon` to `True` won't do anything. Because it will be stuck in your loop after calling `GetMoveCoordinates` above it. If I were you I'd put the while loop in my `Main` to encompass both the get coordinates, and then the drawing of the board as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++) Console.Write(grid[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine()
}
```